# Find top n results of different groups from different tables

Tags: postgresql, nested

I'm getting lost in the logic of how window functions work with nested queries. I have 2 tables that I'm combining, then I need to somehow get the top three results from rows that match certain criteria.

I've tried some intense nesting, but I'm getting lost in how it all works. I have seen other questions like this, but not so much where you first need to join two tables... and i'm not sure where I need to place that in say a window function.

So you have something like:

```
    select name, age, income, location
    from namebank join income_stuff where namebank.name = incomestuff.name


   name | age | income | location
    bob    23    40000    ny
   susan   18    25000    mi
   marty   12     400     ny 
   brent   26    45000    ny
   carl    18    26000    mi
   lana    56    4000     ny   
   raina   30    50000    mi
```

which is fine, but then I need

```
   name | age | income | location
   brent   26    45000    ny
    bob    23    40000    ny
   lana    56    4000     ny 
   raina   30    50000    mi
   carl    18    26000    mi
   susan   18    25000    mi
```

So organized by location with income descending, but just the top three per location.

Comment: Could you explain your expected output a little more? Like do you want the output to be sorted by location and some other attribute? Also Why is the row of "marty" skipped in expected output?

Comment: marty is skipped because I just want the top three. The output is sorted by location; top three incomes per location.

Comment: Never mind, i commented before the edit. Thank you. you did not mention the criteria though. Should I go an an assume by location and income descending?

Comment: yes indeed, sorry. but only the top three per location.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group statements to achieve this. To reduce complexity, I assumed your query as a table "testdata" (you can create a view with your query to imitate this) and formulated the following query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0abb54/17)

the approach used here is ranking each row per group by income. You can uncomment the Count() portion to see what went on in the above link.

So, the total complex query without any view or intermediate tables would be something like this:

```
SELECT testdata.name, testdata.income, testdata.age, testdata.location
FROM 
(select name, age, income, location
    from namebank join income_stuff where namebank.name = incomestuff.name)
AS testdata
LEFT JOIN 
(select name, age, income, location
    from namebank join income_stuff where namebank.name = incomestuff.name) 
AS lesser 
ON testdata.location = lesser.location AND testdata.income < lesser.income
GROUP BY testdata.location, testdata.name, testdata.age, testdata.income
HAVING COUNT(lesser.income) < 3
ORDER BY testdata.location DESC, testdata.income DESC
```

**Edit:**
[This is the sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/81b70/12) assuming a possible config of tables namebank and income_stuff.

Comment: This is cool. Can you explain to me what that left join is actually doing?

Comment: I have this working.. almost. It threw an error until I switched the "where" to an "on" and then it runs.... but never finishes. I don't know if my file is too large or if this is looping somewhere forever.

Comment: I suggest that you run 
```
create view testdata as select name, age, income, location
    from namebank join income_stuff where namebank.name = incomestuff.name
```
Then run the sql in sqlfiddle as is. Does it help?

Comment: it does. Still getting a syntax error at the where in the first nested select statement.
"syntax error at or near where"

Comment: I should clarify: the error comes when I try to run my own actual code. it doesn't come up in sqlfiddle.

Comment: This is weird. Could you please share the structures of namebank and income_stuff tables so that I could write a fiddle tailored for you actual tables?